# LINQ compare two lists, each one inside of an object, at least one equal

Tags: c#, database, linq

I have an object Student

```
public class Student
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public ICollection<WeekDays> weekDays;
}
```

The class WeekDays is like this:

```
public class WeekDays
{
    public Days day;
}
```

And the class Days is like this:

```
public enum Days 
{
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday
    Sunday
}
```

I want to get the students that have at least one common day with a specific student.

I was doing something like this:

```
var student1; //this is a student that have the specific values (id, names and all the weekDays, all initialized with values)

var student2 = database.Students
     .Include(x => x.weekDays)
     .Where(x =>
            x.weekDays.Any(day1 => student1.weekDays.Any(day2 => day2.WorkDay == day1.WorkDay))
     )
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But it's not working, this is the error:

> "(here goes my LINQ expression)" could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try preselect days and use `Contains`:

```
var student1Days = student1.weekDays.Select(d => d.day).ToList();
var student2 = database.Students
     .Include(x => x.weekDays)
     .Where(x => x.weekDays.Any(day1 => student1Days.Contains(day1.WorkDay)))
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: @JakeChavez glad that it helped!